# type TMessage is not a defined class with virtual function C++ builder sample

Tags: c++builder

Im trying to use embarcadero sample on useing android camera and geting an error:

> "type TMessage is not a defined class with virtual function" on lines:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::DoMessageListener(const TObject *Sender, TMessage const *M) {
    TMessageDidFinishTakingImageFromLibrary const *v = dynamic_cast<TMessageDidFinishTakingImageFromLibrary const *>(M);
    if (v) {
        Image1->Bitmap->Assign(v->Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Delphi, [`TMessage`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Messaging.TMessage) works fine, but in C++Builder you must use [`TMessageBase`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Messaging.TMessageBase) instead:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::DoMessageListener(const TObject *Sender, TMessageBase const *M)
```

This is clearly stated in the documentation:

[Sending and Receiving Messages Using the RTL](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Sending_and_Receiving_Messages_Using_the_RTL):

> The RTL only defines one type of message, [`TMessage`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Messaging.TMessage). It is actually a template that you can use to create messages for specific types of values; for example: `TMessage<int>` or `TMessage<UnicodeString>`. You can also subclass [`TMessage`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Messaging.TMessage) to define your own message types or, if you are using FireMonkey, you can reuse the message types defined by the framework.
>
> **Note: For C++ projects use [`TMessageBase`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Messaging.TMessageBase) instead of [`TMessage`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Messaging.TMessage).**

[System.Messaging.TMessage](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Messaging.TMessage)

> `TMessage` represents the base class used for message purposes. It can be inherited in order to send custom messages.
>
> **Warning: For C++ projects, use [`TMessageBase`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Messaging.TMessageBase) instead.**

[System.Messaging.TMessageBase](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Messaging.TMessageBase)

> Alias to [`System.Messaging.TMessage`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Messaging.TMessage).
>
> **Use `System.Messaging.TMessageBase` for C++ projects instead of [`System.Messaging.TMessage`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Messaging.TMessage).**

This use of `TMessageBase` is also demonstrated in the documentation's [System.Messaging (C++)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/en/System.Messaging_(C%2B%2B)) example.